# Jolt Transform using two 2 values to create a new key/value pair

Tags: json, transform, jolt

I have a JSON input that I am transform using JOLT shift. My problem is I want to use the value of an input key, as a new key in the output data, and in parallel add another value into that new outputted key. Here is my input:

```
"Description": {
  "Name": "John",
  "KeyNameId": "John123",
  "Description": "John's description"
}
```

And I want my output to be:

```
"Description": {
  "John123": "John's description"
}
```

Anyway to do this without using two shift operations?
Or with two shifts if one isn't possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be done in a single shift using the "@(Number,words)" operator.

Input - slightly modified for clarity

```
{
  "Top": {
    "Name": "John",
    "KeyNameId": "John123",
    "Description": "John's description"
  }
}
```

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Top": {
        // match the key "Description" and copy it's value to the Output.
        // The Output path being defined by @(1,KeyNameId), which means
        //  go back up the tree 2 levels (0,1) and lookup the value of 
        //  "KeyNameId"
        "Description": "@(1,KeyNameId)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Description": {
        "@Description": "Description.@KeyNameId"
      }
    }
  }
]
```